# Change header background color on other pages in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have following react code.

[My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-active-class-hbesc?file=/src/components/Navigation.js)

What I would like is to when I click on "home" menu background should change on red in other cases on blue.

I write

```
    style={{background: window.location.pathname == "/" ? "red" : "blue"}}
```

but it working only when I am refreshing browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [`useLocation` hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation). `useLocation` allows you to get the current path by doing:

```
let location = useLocation();
console.log(location.pathname);
```

So your problem can be solved by changing your Navigation.js to this:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => (
  <nav
    style={{
      background: useLocation().pathname !== "/" ? "red" : "blue"
    }}
  >
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">
          Home
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/about">
          About
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/contact">
          Contact
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

export default Navigation;
```

You can see the changes in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-active-class-j02fn).

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to declare new styles and assign them using a state variable

in the .css file

```
.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

and then use as follows

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = (props) => {
  
  const [sitestyle, setStyle] = useState("blue");

  return(
  <nav className={sitestyle}>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">
          Home
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/about" onClick={() => {setStyle("red")}}>
          About
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/contact">
          Contact
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
)
  };

export default Navigation;
```